# Magento 2 - language override phtml

Tags: magento2, phtml, language, list.phtml

Is there a way to override a .phtml file on language level?

I have 4 stores (language dependency) and i want to make some changes in the code for these different countries.

I this possible through, let say for instance:

> vendor/store/i18n/de_DE/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml

(this does not work)

Answer (score 0):

If it are just value's you should use the __('text') function and add your translation to a translation file (more info [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/translations/xlate.html)).

If you need conditional information you can use the storemanager $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId(); like they do [here](https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/how-get-store-information-magento-2.html).